# converting chemical substance string to int using mass of atoms

Tags: c++, stoi

i try to make a program that calculate a mass of chemical substance that you put into it. i got stuck on converting string to int to do the math. every time i try to convert i got an error. I am  using visual studio 2022 comunity.

here is code that i have:

and in function "Obliczenia()" i am trying to convert string to int and nothing works as i want. mainly becuse I put string using characters and numbers but converting every element to its mass form is hard for me too and can't do that;

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

string substancja = "";
#define H 1;
#define He 4;
#define Li 7;
#define Be 9;
#define B 11;
#define C 12;
#define N 14;
#define O 16;
#define F 19;
#define Ne 20;
#define Na 23;
#define Mg 24;
#define Al 17;
#define Si 28;
#define P 31;
#define S 32;
#define Cl 35;
#define Ar 40;
#define K 39;
#define Ca 40;
#define Sc 45;
#define Ti 48;
#define V 51;
#define Cr 52;
#define Mn 55;
#define Fe 56;
#define Co 59;
#define Ni 59;
#define Cu 64;
#define Zn 65;
#define Ga 70;
#define Ge 73;
#define As 75;
#define Se 79;
#define Br 80;
#define Kr 84;
#define Rb 85;
#define Sr 88;
#define Y 89;
#define Zr 91;
#define Nb 93;
#define Mo 96;
#define Tc 98;
#define Ru 101;
#define Rh 103;
#define Pd 106;
#define Ag 108;
#define Cd 112;
#define In 115;
#define Sn 119;
#define Sb 122;
#define Te 128;
#define I 127;
#define Xe 131;
#define Cs 133;
#define Ba 137;
#define La 139;
#define Ce 140;
#define Pr 141;
#define Nd 144;
#define Pm 145;
#define Sm 150;
#define Eu 152;
#define Gd 157;
#define Tb 159;
#define Dy 163;
#define Ho 165;
#define Er 167;
#define Tm 169;
#define Yb 173;
#define Lu 175;
#define Hf 178;
#define Ta 181;
#define W 184;
#define Re 186;
#define Os 190;
#define Ir 192;
#define Pt 195;
#define Au 197;
#define Hg 201;
#define Tl 204;
#define Pb 207;
#define Bi 209;
#define Po 209;
#define At 209;
#define Rn 222;
#define Fr 223;
#define Ra 226;
#define Ac 227;
#define Th 232;
#define Pa 231;
#define U 238;
#define Np 237;
#define Pu 244;
#define Am 243;
#define Cm 247;
#define Bk 247;
#define Cf 251;
#define Es 252;
#define Fm 257;
#define Md 258;
#define No 259;
#define Lr 262;
#define Rf 261;
#define Db 263;
#define Sg 265;
#define Bh 264;
#define Hs 269;
#define Mt 268;
#define Ds 281;
#define Rg 280;
#define Cn 285;
#define Nh 284;
#define Fl 289;
#define Mc 288;
#define Lv 292;
#define Ts 294;
#define Og 294;

int obliczenia(string sub)
{
    int wynik;
    vector<int> ilosc(sub.size());
    int dlg;

    for (int i = 0; i < sub.size(); i++)
    {
        ilosc[i] = sub[i];
    }
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i<sub.length(); i++)
        if (i > 0)
        {
            if (sub[i] == 'H')
            {
                sub[i] = H;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'He')
            {
                sub[i] = He;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'Li')
            {
                sub[i] = Li;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'Be')
            {
                sub[i] = Be;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'B')
            {
                sub[i] = B;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'C')
            {
                sub[i] = C;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'N')
            {
                sub[i] = N;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'O')
            {
                sub[i] = O;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'F')
            {
                sub[i] = F;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
            else if (sub[i] == 'Ne')
            {
                sub[i] = Ne;
                sub[i] += '+';
            }
        }
        */
    dlg = stoi(sub);
    cout << dlg;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int wynik;
    cout << "Podaj wzory substancji chemicznej (przykład H2SO4): " << endl;
    cin >> substancja;
    cout << substancja;
    wynik = obliczenia(substancja);

}
```

Comment: `#define` in C++? Why? Macros are evil and best avoided - we have better alternatives (like `const` or `constexpr` variables/constants).

Comment: I think you would want a `std::map` for the mapping between the element name and atomic number.

Comment: I used #define becuse i didn't wanted to put away space in my memory, and using std::map for me now is kinde complicated mayby after some time i can do it

Comment: "I used #define becuse i didn't wanted to put away space in my memory" - That makes no sense. Your values are going to be stored in memory one way or another - otherwise, how would your program be able to work with them?

Comment: I'll change them to int's

Comment: do NOT use `define` for this - it is clear that you do not know what that word actually means in the context of C++: it means to quite literally replace ANY occurance of that identifier with the following string.
so `#define H 1` means that every single future occurence of `H` is replace with the number 1. use a map or anything else.

Comment: Using a `std::map` isn't that hard. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/n3j9feK9d)

Comment: Side note: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: now I see that it is'n that hard thanks

Comment: to make clear I am still teaching in shool on in first class on to this job and we were told there to put "using namespace std" insted of doing std::cout etc. for now it is simpler for me to use this mayby in future i'll stop doing this

Comment: _"mayby in future i'll stop doing this"_ - Yeah, the sooner you get used to not typing `using namespace std;` the better. It has some uses in special situations but it's otherwise mostly causing problems. Especially for beginners - so I don't understand why they teach people to do it at beginner levels.

Comment: ok i'll try to do this as soon as posible, now can we get to main problem i still don't know how to convert string like H2O to int's that are masses of atoms

Comment: Each symbol starts with a capital letter and is followed by 0-2 lowercase letters. When you've extracted a symbol, look it up in the map to get the mass. If it's followed by a number, multiply by that number, then get on to the next symbol.

Comment: You need to **PARSE** the input string. Search for the 1st digit character, extract everything before it, there's your element symbol.  Now search for the next non-digit character, extract the digits before it, there your element count. Repeat until the string is exhausted.  A simpler approach is to have the user break up the input like `H 2 O` instead of `H2O`, then you can simply use `operator>>` to reach each symbol and count for you

Comment: well it works but i don't understand many things and if i want to show this to somone and this person ask me what is going on i can't tell him. it's good that it works but i'm not educated enough to understand this. so for now i want something to be bigger but i can understand this but thanks for help anyway. i came with idea to check every single char but it's to long and it is this or something that is not for my level edit: i don't know why somone telited the comment i refer to

Comment: @qwedirt I deleted the link to my code when I made an answer with explanations out of it. If there is something in my answer that you don't understand, please just ask under the answer and I'll try to explain that part in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

Your current approach is very cumbersome. I suggest that you use a `std::map` in which you can lookup the atomic mass from the element symbols:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string_view>

static const std::map<std::string_view, int> el_am{
    {"H", 1},    {"He", 4},   {"Li", 7},   {"Be", 9},   {"B", 11},
    //...
};
```

Then you need a parsing function to breakdown `H2O` and similar strings. Here's one way to extract a symbol and its multiplier:

- Create an iterator to the beginning of the symbol to be extracted.

  - Use a second iterator to find where the symbol ends. That is, when there are no more lowercase letters or the string is depleted.
  - When that is done, you have an iterator to the beginning and to the end of your symbol. Create a `std::string_view` and look up the mass in the `std::map`.
- Then parse as many digits that follows. For this, you can use `std::from_chars` which will return a result with a pointer to where the parsing stopped.
- You now have the mass and the multiplier. Add the product to a `total_mass` variable.
- Repeat until the whole string is depleted.

Example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <charconv>

int parse(std::string_view str) {
    int total_mass = 0;

    // loop from start to end of the string:
    for (const char *it = str.data(), *const end = it + str.size(); it != end;)
    {
        // extract the symbol
        const char* start = it;

        // find the first non-lowercase char, ignoring the first (start + 1)
        it = std::find_if_not(start + 1, end, [](unsigned char ch) -> bool {
            return std::islower(ch);
        });

        std::string_view sym{start, it}; // create sym from the two iterators
        
        // look up the mass for the symbol
        int this_mass = el_am.at(sym);

        // extract the multiplier
        int mul = 1;
        auto res = std::from_chars(it, end, mul);

        // set `it` to point where from_chars stopped parsing digits
        it = res.ptr;
        std::cout << ' ' << sym << '(' << this_mass << ") x " << mul << '\n'; // debug

        // add the mass for this element multiplied with the multiplier
        total_mass += this_mass * mul;
    }
    return total_mass;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Yr9YacYT6)